# Sign in to twitter with python

Tags: python, twitter, urllib2, python-requests

I want to sign in to twitter with the code below and scrape twitter's data then:

```
import requests
import urllib2

with requests.Session() as c:
    url = "https://twitter.com/login"
    USER = "hadishamgholi74@gmail.com"
    PASS = "52518685251868"
    c.get(url)
    login_data = {"session[username_or_email]": USER, "session[password]": PASS, "authenticity_token": "4d1c2137136cb297b3e83e382b0026d9213fe731", "scribe_log": "", "redirect_after_login": "", "authenticity_token": "4d1c2137136cb297b3e83e382b0026d9213fe731"}
    c.post(url,data = login_data,headers={"Referer":"https://twitter.com"})
    page = c.get("https://twitter.com")
    print page.content
```

But it rise this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/Mehdi/PycharmProjects/scrap/login1.py", line 9, in <module>
        c.get(url)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 473, in get
        return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 461, in   request
        resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 573, in send
        r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 431, in send
        raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:581)
```

What should i do?

Comment: nice job posting your Twitter login and password...

Comment: that's nothing i don't use twitter at all except for a project. if u want u can use it.

Comment: _scrap_ (ie: throw away) twitter's data, or _scrape_ (ie: gather) it?

Comment: that not related to my code but actually it's scrape.sorry for mistake.

Comment: scrape tweets? all tweets? specific tweets? Its much better using a twitter api like tweepy

Comment: please forget scraping. I just want to log in to twitter with python.

Answer (score 0):

According to this post, there is not support for the `https` protocol yet [requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 8] _ssl.c:504: EOF occurred in violation of protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675872/requests-exceptions-sslerror-errno-8-ssl-c504-eof-occurred-in-violation-of)

Comment: this means i can never access to a https protocol (with python) at all?

Comment: Not unless you download the pre-release for version 2.0

Comment: you mean the pre-release version 2 for module requests ?  but i didn't find it if you know where please help me

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know where it is either